# How do I branch into a specified part of a loop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, branch

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    b = sc.nextInt();
    a =+ b;
    c =+ (a + 1);
    if (c < 20) {
        i = 2;
    }
}
```

if I have lines numbered from 0 to 6 inside the loop, the loop would be
so if c is less than 20, it repeats the operation "c=+(a+1);" until it breaks out of the loop by c>=20.

this is a simplified code from my program, mine is GUI. every time I run the code, it freezes.

Comment: The question is unclear. Please clarify. An example will help.

Comment: if(c<20){}else{break;}

Comment: @shruti1810 the code above is an example I guess. I find it hard to branch into an operation inside a loop.

Comment: What do you mean it freezes? You realize that it's waiting for input each time it hits the first line inside of the loop?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do with `a =+ b;`, since I'm guessing that is converted to 'a' equals 'unary plus' b. Did you mean `a += b;`?

Comment: @DAO it still freezes

Comment: @swingman it freezes when I input the number the first time

Comment: @Water I have tried that.

Comment: @Nee I am able to make your code terminate, you have to tell us the input. I can't really proceed to give you a proper answer until then.

Comment: @Water the input for example is 0

Comment: @Nee Only once? Like you just submit 0, and then it freezes?

Comment: @Water yes it totally freezes

Comment: @Nee It freezes because you have sc.nextInt() in for loop and I am sure that at first run there is nothing in stdin

Comment: @Nee add this before b = sc.nextInt();.  while (sc.hasNextInt()==false) {}

Comment: @Nee do you only want to read one single value from the command line?

Comment: @Nee are you running from Eclipse.? If so don't forget to  click in the console window before typing input otherwise your input scanner won't be active.

Answer (score 0):

You can tag a loop and do `break` or `continue` instructions, but you need design the flow, it is not possible to go into specified line, because java don't use `goto` instruction. You can only switch the flow inside loops by those instructions.

```
myloopTag: 
for (...; ...; ...) {
    // and you can break current loop by:
    break;

    // or specific (outer) loop by
    break myloopTag;

    // you can also use 'continue' to go to the start of the loop and increment again
    continue;

    // or to 'continue' at a label:
    continue myloopTag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use     `c+=` instead of `c=+`. try that, cheers!
and `b+=` instead of`b=+`.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably very new to the language. Welcome!

If I understand your description of your intent properly, you want your code to exit the loop when c>=20. Based on your description of numbering your lines and the fact that you have the statement:

```
if(c<20){
    i=2;
}
```

it seems that you think that the iterator i in the for loop is related to the line that will be executed*. This is not the case. The iterator i is a variable that simply holds an integer (just like `a`, `b`, and `c` in your code).

I suggest you take a look at a [tutorial on for loops](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). It might be helpful for you to review other language basics as well, like [how control flow works](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html) (this may be a better one to start with, actually).

*This guess at your intent is further supported by you counting that there are 6 lines and that your loop goes up to 6.

Comment: In more details, I have a loop that takes in mathematical operations and a switch case in which it translates those operations in order to apply addition or subtraction.. etc.

Comment: The loop (int i) is the number of operations it reads. The condition is also a part of the operations entered, it's also inside the switch case. So whenever the user enters that condition, and the number (for instance j) that the loop should repeat, the program should take in j and equalizes it with i but it freezes. I want it to branch to that part of the loop where the user defines to get the condition right.

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand all the details of what you're trying to accomplish. If you're having trouble with your program freezing, or aren't sure why it's executing certain things at certain times, you might want to watch your program line by line as it executes. There are many tools you can use for this (called IDE's) that have debuggers included in them that let you "step" through code line by line while watching variable values and other useful info. Eclipse is a popular tool you could use for this. Take a look [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html).